# How do I git out of this mess with a git submodule?

Tags: wordpress, git, git-submodules, git-checkout, git-reset

I've got a git repo with Wordpress as a submodule. I was trying to update Wordpress and really screwed things up. I just want to get all of the code from the 3.7.1 tag in the remote repository, but this doesn't work;

```
git fetch --tags
git checkout 3.7.1
```

Leaves a bunch of either "untracked files" or "uncommitted changes". I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I've tried so many things to get this submodule onto the 3.7.1 tag and nothing seems to work. If anything, I feel like I'm just making the problem worse. It shouldn't be that hard to just reset the code from the tag I want and discard everything else. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the git nuclear option:

```
git clean -dfx             # delete everything in the worktree that isn't tracked
git reset --hard           # wipe all modifications to tracked files
git checkout 3.7.1
```

which looks appropriate here.

Comment: Thanks. Yes. This is what I ended up doing. In this case it didn't matter, but for future reference; does `git clean -dfx` delete ignored files as well?